# Optimize conditional calling to functions

Tags: c#, code-analysis

Is there a much efficient or better way to rewrite this code?

```
if (condition 1 = true)
{
    // Call to function 1
}

if (condition 2 = true)
{
    // Call to function 2
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that short answer is NO. Long answer depends on conditions and functions.

Answer (score 1):

In general, no.

If  the called functions re-evaluate the condition, then perhaps yes, by lifting the part of the function that re-evaluates the condition out of the function, since the condition is known to be true.  (This is called "partial evaluation").

If condition1 and condition2 have a relationship, then perhaps yes.  Imagine that condition1 is composed of several terms

```
   c1a and c1b and .. c1n
```

and that c2 is composed of

```
   c2a and c2b and ... c2m
```

If some subset of the c1i implies some subset of the c2j,  then you can evaluate the conditions more efficiently:

```
    if   (c1isubset)  {
         if  (c1irest)
            { // call to function 1
            }
         endif
         if (c2jrest)
            { // call to function2)
            }
    }
```

Of course, it may be that a subset of c2j implies a subset of c1i, and then you'd swap the order of tests around.